# Process name is set from Python but it is not visible from outside

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, terminal, multiprocessing

I have a complex multiprocessing Python project which starts about 8-10 processes. These processes get different unique names and these names works fine inside the code. But if I check the running processes in a Terminal these processes don't have unique names. They have the same name as their parent's name (Actually the command line itself).

**Used environment:**

- Python 3.6.6
- RedHat Linux 7
- xfce4-terminal 0.8.7.4

**A minimal code:**

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def sleeping_function(s_time):
    multiprocessing.current_process().name = "process_{}".format(s_time)
    print(multiprocessing.current_process().name)
    time.sleep(s_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    times = [200, 201, 202, 203, 204]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=len(times)) as pool:
        results = pool.map(sleeping_function, times)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
process_200
process_201
process_202
process_203
process_204
```

Check the running processes in my terminal (while the all processes are running in script).

**Command:**

```
ps  aux -u my_user_name | grep python
```

**Output:**

```
my_user_name 888273  0.1  0.0 359804 11288 pts/162  Sl+  15:10   0:00 python3 test.py
my_user_name 888274  0.0  0.0 138608  8040 pts/162  S+   15:10   0:00 python3 test.py
my_user_name 888275  0.0  0.0 138608  8056 pts/162  S+   15:10   0:00 python3 test.py
my_user_name 888276  0.0  0.0 138608  8056 pts/162  S+   15:10   0:00 python3 test.py
my_user_name 888277  0.0  0.0 138608  8060 pts/162  S+   15:10   0:00 python3 test.py
my_user_name 888278  0.0  0.0 138608  8060 pts/162  S+   15:10   0:00 python3 test.py
```

I would like to see the `process_20X`process name instead of the called Python command.

**My question:**

Is it possible to provide unique name to processes from Python script which are visible outside (eg.: from a terminal)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [setproctitle](https://pypi.org/project/setproctitle/) module to change the system name for the process. Obviously the module calls into the C-routine with the same name.

```
setproctitle.setproctitle(multiprocessing.current_process().name)
```

It works for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your solution works on RedHat Linux as well and it absolutely solves my issue!